# is it right way in obj-c programming

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, properties, implementation, declare

i wonder if the way i programm is right way or not. can you help me?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UILabel *messageLabel;
}
@end
```

when i declare new object in .h and create in .m i have to use `@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabel`? i saw few listings where when object are created by code `@property` doesn't exist and few where does exist and i'm confused.

is it correct when i don't use @property (in example for `UILabel`, `UIImageView`, `UIButton`) when i create objects by code?

Comment: You only need @property if you intend to use the info in those objects to pass between views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@property` is a key word useful to create setter/getter methods automatically for that field. If you don't need to access your label from outside your view controller you won't need to use `@property` and your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. `@property` is used globally throughout your app, rather than being specific to your `UIViewController`. If you are only planning on referring or changing the label/other component define it within the `{ }` otherwise `@property` should be used